# what if somehow maintain the flow of electrons in this way

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields, energy-conservation

what if somehow maintain the flow of electrons in this way

[image]

how long electron will keep flowing & how much electricity (energy) it generates?

Answer (score 0):

Electrons can flow around superconducting wires forever. They use these in MRI machines as magnets.

No energy is generated.

Comment: but flow of electrons generates electricity

Comment: @RajTripathi flow of electrons ***is*** electricity